# Remove headerbars from gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I would like to have a terminal window without the headerbar to save up space (like tiling window managers). I have tried solutions like enabling extensions (pixel-saver) but didn't work. I have also set `headerbar false` with `gsettings` with no change. Is there any solution?